# Inverse Fourier transform of cut off of Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose we have a function $f(x)$ such that $$|\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)| \leq C(1 + |x|)^{-n}$$
Take the Fourier transform $\hat{f}(\xi)$ and consider the function $g(\xi) = \chi(\xi)\hat{f}(\xi)$, where $\chi(\xi)$ is a smooth function supported away from the origin and $\chi(\xi) \equiv 1$ outside $[-1, 1]$. What can we say about the the decay properties of the inverse Fourier transform of $g(\xi)$?

Edit: This is not a homework assignment. I am currently attending a course on Fourier analysis, and we used a cut-off function in a calculation today. I am trying to play around a bit with this concept. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is perhaps easier to consider $g(\xi) = \hat{f}(\xi) - (1 - \chi(\xi)) \hat{f}(\xi)$. Using that $1 - \chi$ is $C^\infty_0$ you can take the inverse Fourier transform of the second part and see that it is the convolution of $f$ with some $\mathcal{S}$ function. This should answer your question.